# Inverse of a function in 2-variables

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function

I'm working on a differential geometry question using flows, and I'm trying to find the inverse of a specific curve (specifically a curve at a regular point).

The function is: $\psi(t,s)=(\frac{1}{2}s(e^{t}+e^{-t}),\frac{1}{2}s(e^{t}-e^{-t}))$, and I want the inverse to be of the form $\psi^{-1}(x,y)=(f(x,y),g(x,y))$ (inverse meaning composition both ways reduces to the identity i.e. $\frac{1}{2}g(x,y)(e^{f(x,y)}+e^{-f(x,y)})=x$ and the same for $y$).

Any ideas for the inverse? The fact that $t$ and $s$ aren't separable here is what's causing me so much trouble, and I think some clever usage of the $ln$ function or something similar could help me work it out, but so far I'm having no luck. Is there a general way to approach these types of problems? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm rusty on my algebra, so I may have made a mistake with what you're describing, but the "switching/solving" leaves me with $\frac{1}{2}y(e^x+e^{-x})=t$ and $\frac{1}{2}y(e^x-e^{-x})=s$. From there by adding we can get relations such as $s+t=ye^x$, but I still don't see quite how to finish up the problem.

Comment: Mmm, of course. Yes, I'm looking for local coordinates in a neighborhood of $(1,0)$ so I don't think I would need a global inverse. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You have  $(x+y)/(x-y) = e^{2t}$ and $x^2-y^2= s^2$, that allows to determine $t$, and $s$.